# How to save the selected value of spinner to sqlite database?

Tags: android

I want to save the value which is selected in spinner. I had tried same way as we do for the edit text. The text are getting saved but not the spinner values.

```
public void action(View v)

{

switch(v.getId())
{

case R.id.button1:

    String spinner_taluka=tv4.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String comment=tv5.getText().toString();


    if(comment==null||comment==""||comment.length()<3)
    {
        show("Please add comment");
    }
    if(spinner_taluka==null)
    {
        show("Select one item");
    }

    else
    {
        db.execSQL("insert into employee values('"+spinner_taluka+"','"+comment+"','nothing')");
        i=new Intent(this,Success.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 500);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left); 
        db.close();
        finish();
    }

    break;
}
```

But this is not working.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you getting value on spinner_taluka ?

Comment: anywhere showing error ?. try to debug and find error

Comment: Have you tried with using ContentValues?

Comment: try this @UjwalaPanchbhai
 
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO employee (field_name1, field_name2, field_name3) " + " Values (" + spinner_taluka + ", '" + comment+ "', nothing "');");

Comment: ok, let me try it out.

Comment: for nothing its giving that, had used the flag while creating the table.

Comment: db=openOrCreateDatabase("schooldata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("create table if not exists employee(spinner_taluka varchar,comment varchar,flag varchar)");

Comment: change (field_name1, field_name2, field_name3) with your values. like - (spinner_taluka,comment ,flag)

Comment: ya i had done that too previously, it saves the value but not properly, fields are mismatching.

Comment: ohh...its saving values on database. the problem is fields mismatching ?

Comment: ya, in database it stores the value as : below comment heading, spinner value is stored and below flag, comment. Its not showing the spinner tag in table